# Do the Saar need to wait a whole round to build a Space Dock?

Tags: twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-3rd-edition

Most races in Twilight Imperium need to wait a whole round in order to build a Space Dock from the moment they take control of a system, that is because of the following requirement in the rules (emphasis mine):

> The active player must have controlled **the planet** for the entire
>   current round. Thus, it is not possible to build a Space Dock on a
>   planet that has just been acquired during the current round.

However, the Saar do not build their Space Docks on planets, as specified on their racial sheet. So, can they build a Space Dock wherever they want immediately as they control a system, or do they need to wait a round like all other races?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From page 10 of the [Twilight Imperium FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Twilight%20Imperium%203/ti3faq.pdf) (version 2.5):

> *Q: What are the restrictions for building a Saar Space Dock?*
>
> A: The player must control 1 planet in the system per space dock he wishes to
>   build. Trade stations do not count towards this restriction.

From this the Saar need to have control of a planet, so I would think that why the rule you quoted on needing to have controlled the planet for the entire round would apply.

Comment: So thematically.... I guess they build it on the planet and launch it? OK, I guess I got my answer. Missed that FAQ..